# Каким запросом удалить строки из таблицы sql

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице product есть description в котором есть табличка текст и картинка. Каким запросом удалить эти данные. Информация в табличке разная, как и текст. Нужен запрос типа удалить с `<table>` и заканчивающееся `<img>`. После картинки есть ещё инфа и её нужно оставить. Совсем чайник в этом деле, спасайте.

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос нужна схема таблицы и пример её содержимого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить подстроку от начала до тега `<table>` (даже с учётом возможного наличия в нём атрибутов) несложно:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '<table', 1)
```

Получить подстроку после тега `<img>` (а вот там атрибуты есть точно) чуть сложнее:

```
SUBSTRING(description FROM LOCATE(description, '>', LOCATE(description, '<img')) + 1)
```

Осталось сцепить и обновить:

```
UPDATE table
SET description = CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '<table', 1),
                          SUBSTRING(description FROM LOCATE(description, '>', LOCATE(description, '<img')) + 1)
                        )
```

Однако для обновляемых записей необходимо убедиться, что в description имеются теги `<table>` и `<img>`, причём второй после первого, а то получится хрень.

В итоге получаем:

```
UPDATE table
SET description = CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '<table', 1),
                          SUBSTRING(description FROM LOCATE(description, '>', LOCATE(description, '<img')) + 1)
                        )
WHERE LOCATE(description, '<table') BETWEEN 1 AND LOCATE(description, '<img')
```